# Rails 4 + Omniauth + Devise: Logout link not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm using Omniauth as my only method for signing into my Rails application.

The issue is: When a user clicks "Logout", the page reloads and the Logout link is still there (despite if user_signed_in? logic wrapping it). Which leads me to believe that users aren't actually getting logged out

Here's my **index.html.erb**:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Authenticate with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<% end %>
```

And my **user.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  if user = User.find_by_email(auth.info.email)
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user
  else
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email # THIS (user.email) value i want to provide to my registration form as default value
   end
  end
end
```

And my **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController 
  skip_before_filter :redirect_to_login_if_required
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      return
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = @user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
end
```

And my **routes.rb**:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

Unfortunately it's not bringing me back an error. It's just refreshing the index page as if nothing happened.

**Edit: Here's the POST when I click Logout**

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for ::1 at 2015-07-06 11:00:22 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"7QXScU8eVW6NVedKG5P86rPxkaP8uJdUzyJ712ZrYXtK7QjP/m33eQ2WE/ituUvFQ2GeenXLRBaiVibxEjHG6w=="}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Edit 2: I've included this in my application_controller.rb**

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

And now the error message I'm getting in the console is:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=c92f3f9e0a8db79485e56ec2a1defd91949e8e7d99a02130&code=4/pgl_HZFw113L7VJ-rSaV9-JYngABkfgx7lqRm06Dyqg" for ::1 at 2015-07-06 16:12:14 -0400
I, [2015-07-06T16:12:14.739138 #2442]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#google_oauth2 as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"c92f3f9e0a8db79485e56ec2a1defd91949e8e7d99a02130", "code"=>"4/pgl_HZFw113L7VJ-rSaV9-JYngABkfgx7lqRm06Dyqg"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "broy@gmail.com"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-07-06 20:11:47.636852"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-07-06 20:12:15.365770"], ["sign_in_count", 42], ["updated_at", "2015-07-06 20:12:15.366734"], ["id", 4]]
   (1.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-07-06 16:12:15 -0400
Processing by ProductlinesController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Please update your post with `/config/initializers/devise.rb`

Comment: Is jquery-ujs correctly loaded and working? Otherwise the `:method => :delete` part of the link (which is required) won't work. Try checking the web inspector/server logs see if a DELETE call is indeed being sent.

Comment: Do you have this line `config.sign_out_via = :delete` commented out in your /config/initializers/devise.rb? If so uncomment it and check.

Comment: Nope - config.sign_out_via = :delete is in there.

Comment: Can you post the log generated when you click on logout?

Comment: Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for ::1 at 2015-07-06 11:00:22 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"7QXScU8eVW6NVedKG5P86rPxkaP8uJdUzyJ712ZrYXtK7QjP/m33eQ2WE/ituUvFQ2GeenXLRBaiVibxEjHG6w=="}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend switching the if to unless, so it shows the logout link when the user is signed in.

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Authenticate with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<% end %>
```

When using devise, an alternative way of displaying the corrects links is:

```
<%unless current_user.blank? -%>
  <%= link_to "Authenticate with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
<%else -%>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<%end-%>
```

Comment: This is still giving me "Authenticate with Google" all the time, even after I authenticate.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that sign in is working? Would you mind posting the editing the post to include the logs?

Comment: Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for ::1 at 2015-07-06 11:00:22 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"7QXScU8eVW6NVedKG5P86rPxkaP8uJdUzyJ712ZrYXtK7QjP/m33eQ2WE/ituUvFQ2GeenXLRBaiVibxEjHG6w=="}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: @beaconhill - If you were referring to the Authenticate with Google always showing up with the code above, it seems like the user isn't signed in so the sign out functionality wouldn't work.

Comment: But when I look at the user record in Admin, the "Current sign in at" timestamp is the time I click login and the "Sign in count" increases...

Comment: However, when I go incognito, I still see the "Logout" link with your code above.

Comment: I'm getting Completed 401 Unauthorized when I put before_action :authenticate_user! in application_controller.rb

Answer (score 2):

From the ***logs*** you posted, you have

> Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected

This is the reason for your problem.

Adding `skip_before_filter :verify_signed_out_user` to your controller should solve the problem.

***Update:***

You need to change your code in ***index.html.erb*** to the following

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Authenticate with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
<% end %>
```

***Source:*** [**Devise Wiki**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template)

Comment: I added it to my omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb but I'm still getting Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected.

Comment: This is what it currently looks like:   skip_before_filter :redirect_to_login_if_required, :verify_signed_out_user

Comment: @beaconhill I think you should add it to `users_controller.rb`

Comment: I do not have a users_controller.rb. I generated the user model via Devise.

Comment: @beaconhill Sorry you should add it in your `sessions_controller.rb`

Comment: I have added it to the controller that is handling sessions (  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
) and I'm still seeing the same error message.

Comment: @beaconhill I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: I am successfully signing in, but now I don't see the Logout link. All i see is "Authenticate with Google" even when I am signed in.

Comment: @beaconhill That's weird!

Comment: It's almost as if there's no active session. It's logging a login to the count on the user, but they're not actively logged in or out ever.

Comment: hi @Pavan is thier any progress on this error `Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected`  . I get it in console when i try to logout from activeadmin and the admin users are not being redirected to the login page. am using devise, jwt in rails api